# What's the best way to setup git when having common code that should be used in several repositories?

Tags: .net, git, github, kanban

I'm working as a .NET developer in a development team where we are using kanban for our software development process. We are currently using team foundation server for source control and having a branch-by-feature strategy to ensure that we allways have releasable code.

Since there is some "limitations" in Team Foundation Server we are about to move to github to get a more flexible tool.

There for I wonder what's the best way to setup git when you have a common project that should be used from several solutions/applications? Should it be a repository of it's own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, every project (and I don't mean Visual Studio meaning of that word) should have its own repository, including the common project. You can then use [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to include it into the other projects.